# Correctly Breaking from Nested For Loops in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested-loops, createjs

Having some trouble with nested for loops. I have one big array called pointArray, and then a few smaller colorArrays made up of values from the pointArray. I want to 
1) figure out the index of player 1's position in the pointArray 
2) count UP from that index in the point array until a match is found in the colorArray
3) return the matching index in the color array (I called that variable "dest")
4) move the player to that destination using tweenJS.

Step 1 is working correctly, and step 4 is working to an extent. Instead of moving a player to the next destination in the colorArray, it keeps moving the player to colorArray[0], due to the fact that variable dest = 0, which means that my for loop is not storing the value of dest correctly. I suspect that my issue has to do with the scope of my counter variables and an error in the nested for loop.

```
var pointArray = [{x:70, y:500},
    {x:120, y:500},...];
var currentPos, dest;

function findPoint(color) {

for (var i=0; i < pointArray.length; i++) {
    if (player1.x === pointArray[i].x && player1.y === pointArray[i].y) {
        currentPos = i;
        break;
    }
}
var m = currentPos + 1;    
for(m;m<pointArray.length; m++) {
    for(var n=0;n<color.length; n++){
        if (color[n].x === pointArray[m].x && color[n].y === pointArray[m].y) {
            dest = n;
            break;   
        }
        break;
    }
}

createjs.Tween.get(player1)
    .wait(500)
    .to({x:color[dest].x,y:color[dest].y}, 1000, createjs.Ease.quadIn);
}
```

Update: code fixed using "break checks"

```
var breakCheck1;
for(m;m<pointArray.length; m++) {
    for(var n=0;n<color.length; n++){
        if (color[n].x === pointArray[m].x && color[n].y === pointArray[m].y) {
            dest = n;
            breakCheck1= true;
            break;
        } else {console.log("This loop ran but didn't catch");}
    if (breakCheck1) {break;}
    }
if (breakCheck1) {break;}
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that the inside loop is running more than once?

Comment: Add a bunch of console.log([stuff to be logged]) everywhere and figure out what's happening using chrome's console. I'm not seeing a problem when I briefly look at it. It's usually much easier to find bugs in code like this when you can run it and log stuff.

Comment: I got the logic loop to work by updating the code using "breakchecks". However, I am unconvinced that this is the most concise way of doing so. Are there any more efficient solutions?

Comment: `if (breakCheck1) {break;}` should be `if (breakCheck1) break;` -- You don't need the curly braces for one-line `if` statements.

Comment: Check out some of the examples here. You can name loops, and use the name to break them. Super handy! http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_loop_control.htm